# How to auto the process of "javacc -> compile with custom compiler -> compile" with maven?

Tags: java, maven, javacc

My process is as follow:

1. Use javacc to compile my *.jj files and generate my own compiler.
2. Use my own compiler to compile source code that with my special syntax
   into normal java code.
3. Compile all Java code into *.class file as usual.

Currently I do these works manually. Is there any way that I can do all these works automatically through maven when I build the project?

Comment: Did you have a look into writing your own mojos?

Comment: Have you tried something? Maybe using a batch/sh file with the instruction/commands you are executing manually could be one way to solve your problem...

Comment: @Thomas I thought that if there are some plugins already exist would be better, If I cannot achieve that goal without creating my own plugin, I will consider it.

Comment: @araknoid Yes, I currently use shell script to do that, but that way the project would not cross-platform, I need the project could be used in any platform.